# Cant store the Firebase nide key in local storage

Tags: angular, firebase

I am trying to store the key of the firebase node as soon as it is created into the local storage but it says setItem won't take null value.
this is my service component

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FireserviceService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    
   }
  private create(){
      return this.db.list('/shopping-carts').push({
      dateCreated:new Date().getTime()
    });
  }
  
  private getCart(cartId:string){
     return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/'+ cartId);
  }
  public async getOrCreateCart(){
    let cartId=localStorage.getItem('cartId');
    if(!cartId){
      
      let result= await this.create();
      let val=result.key;
      localStorage.setItem('cartId',result.key);
      console.log(val)
      
    }
    return this.getCart("");
  }
  
}
```

this is my brain component

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FireserviceService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    
   }
  private create(){
      return this.db.list('/shopping-carts').push({
      dateCreated:new Date().getTime()
    });
  }
  
  private getCart(cartId:string){
     return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/'+ cartId);
  }
  public async getOrCreateCart(){
    let cartId=localStorage.getItem('cartId');
    if(!cartId){
      
      let result= await this.create();
      let val=result.key;
      localStorage.setItem('cartId',result.key);
      console.log(val)
      
    }
    return this.getCart("");
  }
  
}
```

I am trying to call getOrCreateCart from the brain component and create a cart or get a cart in-service component. As soon as a cart is created I want to store the key in the local storage so that the same user doesn't create several nodes in my firebase. But in the service component

```
localStorage.setItem('cartId',result.key);
```

won't work. for the second argument result.key it says "Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)".
While if the console.log(val) or console.log(result.key) it will print the key in the console.
Please help me. I have searched through the internet a lot did not find any answer. It's been a week and I am stuck with this.

Answer (score 0):

result.key might be string **or** null. `localStorage.setItem(key, value);` only accepts a string and not null, therefore you need to provide a default value in case result.key is null:

```
localStorage.setItem('cartId',result.key ?? '');
```